# ValueAnimator for count up effect on Android TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, android-animation, animator

I am trying to make a cout-up effect in a TextView for a double value like this:

```
ValueAnimator animator = new  ValueAnimator();
animator.setObjectValues(0, 50.5); //double value
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(animation.getAnimatedValue()));
            }
        });
animator.setEvaluator(new TypeEvaluator<Double>() { // problem here
   @Override
   public Double evaluate(float fraction, Double startValue, Double endValue) {
      return  (startValue + (endValue - startValue) * fraction);
           }
        });
animator.setDuration(3000);
animator.start();// problem here
```

It gave me this: **java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double** at the line **animator.setEvaluator(new TypeEvaluator()** at **animator.start();**

If I use the count up for a integer and implement The TypeEvaluator method, it works. Why not for a double?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`animator.setObjectValues(0, 50.5);`  in this line 0 consider as `int` value

change this line to

`animator.setObjectValues(0d, 50.5d)`; //double value

Comment: that did the trick, thanks, I wasn't paying attention to the 0 value!

Answer (score 3):

Here the **ClassCastException** occurred as the return type of evaluator is double.But some arithmetic operation is done in the return statement where the float (**fraction**) value is multiplied by double value (**endValue - startValue**) where the compiler gets confused as it does not know which value is going to be returned.Hence typecast the value of  **(endValue - startValue) * fraction** to double.After modifications the code should look like

```
ValueAnimator animator = new  ValueAnimator();
    animator.setObjectValues(0d, 50.5d); //double value
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(animation.getAnimatedValue()));
                }
            });
    animator.setEvaluator(new TypeEvaluator<Double>() { // problem here
       @Override
       public Double evaluate(float fraction, Double startValue, Double endValue) {
          return  (startValue + (double)((endValue - startValue) * fraction));
               }
            });
    animator.setDuration(3000);
    animator.start();
```

Comment: adding (double) in front of (endValue - startValue) * fraction is redundant because the inspection reports a double value

Comment: cast the product to double like (double)((endValue - startValue) * fraction)

Comment: It's the same thing, still redundant, the problem was that I forgot to put "d" after 0 at setObjectValues.